# Send email with attachment from WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently using Process.Start to send simple emails from my WinForms app. Can you think of any way to add a file attachment to the email? (Edit: using Process.Start?)

Here's what I use now:

```
Process.Start("mailto:test@test.invalid?subject=" + HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("Application error report") + "&body=" + body);
```

Comment: Similar Post Here -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-mailto-with-attachment

Comment: Flag as duplicate of [Sending email from Command-line via outlook without having to click send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433202/sending-email-from-command-line-via-outlook-without-having-to-click-send). (The solutions below all use this.) Actually a better duplicate would be [C# MailTo with Attachment? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment?noredirect=1&lq=1) since the second answer **directly answers this question**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this -->

```
MailMessage theMailMessage = new MailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com");
theMailMessage.Body = "body email message here";
theMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("pathToEmailAttachment"));
theMailMessage.Subject = "Subject here";

SmtpClient theClient = new SmtpClient("IP.Address.Of.Smtp");
theClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential theCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@name.com", "password");
theClient.Credentials = theCredential;
theClient.Send(theMailMessage);
```

---

Alright, based on your edit and additional info, I found this Blog Post by [Jon Galloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5/jon-galloway), ["Sending files via the default e-mail client"](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/sending-files-via-the-default-e-mail-client.aspx).

This looks like what you may be looking for, though I don't profess any knowledge with this way as I have always used the method I posted.

Hopefully it is of use to you.

Comment: Important question I forgot to ask.  How do you want to send it?  Outlook, Google, ect....

Comment: +1 That will teach me for spending time seeing if this was even possible using Process.Start :) Turns out that you can't add attachments that way, so the already correct System.Net.Mail becomes an even better answer.

Comment: What's funny, is if you search my old posts on SO, I posted an almost identical question almost a year ago.  I guess this is me giving back!  I love SO!

Comment: The user's default email client opens and presents the message ready to send. I have avoided using SmtpClient thus far because I didn't want to turn my program into an email client. It may be a support issue for the user to find and edit in their email host name. I was hoping someone knew a trick for Process.Start... I should have made this more clear.

Comment: MAPISendMail seems to work with win7-64 and Thunderbird which is the only email client I have for testing. The wrapper class code is linked to in the Galloway article. I guess a lot of users won't even be using a local email client nowadays (gmail) so don't know what I will do about that.