# Sending Email With Attachment C#

Tags: c#, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email with attachment from WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204698/send-email-with-attachment-from-winforms-app)

Here is my script:

```
     var fromAddress = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
     var toAddress = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
     const string fromPassword = "mypassword";
     const string subject = "Subject";
     const string body = "Body";

       var smtp = new SmtpClient
       {
           Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
           Port = 587,
           EnableSsl = true,
           DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
           UseDefaultCredentials = false,
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
       };
       using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                 {
                     Subject = subject,
                     Body = body,
                 })

       {
           smtp.Send(message);
       }
```

It works well, yet I am yet to come up with a way to add an attachment. Yes, I know this site has examples, but I cannot find one that will send an attachment

Comment: That's a script? It looks just like a computer program to me.

Comment: Try a Google search with "c# send attachment".  The first set of results should give you what you want.

Comment: -1 absolutely no research effort: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=send+email+attachment+stackoverflow+c%23 -> first link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204698/send-email-with-attachment-from-winforms-app

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Attachments property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx).