# e-mail app error : cannot access a disposed object (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

New to programming; I want an app to send mails with attachments and close automatically as soon as it's done. Using the code below but it throws up the "Exception Unhandled: System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Automail
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("abc@xyz.com", "bcd@xyz.com");
            message.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
            message.Subject = "Exeption Reports";
            message.Body = @"Find attached generated exception reports.";
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:/New folder/STOCKS_NOT_MOVED.txt"));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.xyz.com";
            client.Port = 25;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@xyz.com", "password");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            // client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in SendEmail(): {0}",
                        ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Goodbye!");
            }
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did u try this.Close() instead of Close(). First you need to check whether email is sending using mail message then close the form. Are you facing issue with closing form or sending email?

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204698/send-email-with-attachment-from-winforms-app

Comment: Hi, the mail sends. The issue is with closing form. Thanks.

Comment: why didi you try to sned email in InitializeComponent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to close a form in the constructor. InitializeComponent is called from constructor I believe.

actually you do not need a form, try ordinary class

```
class MailHelper
{
    public void SendMail()
    {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("abc@xyz.com", "bcd@xyz.com");
            message.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
            message.Subject = "Exeption Reports";
            message.Body = @"Find attached generated exception reports.";
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:/New folder/STOCKS_NOT_MOVED.txt"));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.xyz.com";
            client.Port = 25;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@xyz.com", "password");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            // client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

you can use it like `new MailHelper().SendMail();`