# Does the mailto: in anchor tag actually support attachments?

Tags: html, email, outlook, anchor, mailto

Is it possible to have attachments to be specified in the mailto: tag in HTML?

< a href="test@test.com?body=somebody&subject=someSubject">my link < /a>

if yes, how can I specify an attachment on:

1. In the user's machine
2. At the server

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-mailto-with-attachment

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, and it is important, `mailto` is not a "tag", it's a [URL scheme](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html). Secondly, no, the scheme only allows you to supply values for [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) headers. There may be hacks supported by particular MUAs, but they won't be portable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about with mailto but the `/a` switch can be used with Outlook.
A Help search in Outlook on "command-line switches" gives details.
Naturally, since this is an Outlook-only switch and you need the path to
Outlook there are limitations (as well as possibly limitations imposed by
file access from the Web).