# Attach files using <a href="mailto:?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook

I have the following code snippet:
It is opens the outlook with mail subject, but failed to attach files. Actually i am trying attach two files in MVC4 view, thats why MailAttachment[0].

```
   <a href="mailto:?subject=@(Model.MailSubject)&Attachment=@(Model.MailAttachment[0])">
        <img src="~/Images/mail.png" />
   </a>
```

I don't required to call any action methods, so that am trying to open the outlook in view itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot attach client side files using mailto with server side code (Razor code), unless you give a RIGHT path to client side file.

First you need to make the user download the file to the clientside. Then ask him to use that file to attach in the email.

Also MailTo Scheme [doesn't support Attachments officially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517046/does-the-mailto-in-anchor-tag-actually-support-attachments).

As an alternative, you can send email from server side itself using [System.Net.Mail namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, mailto doesn't support attachments :(
Achieved the same by following links,
  1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb644320.aspx
  2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148639/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-window-c-sharp

Comment: @Sanooj VS Wouldn't this open outlook on the server side and not on the local machine?