# Adding a dynamic attachment to an email in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mailmessage

Folks,
Using the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:` method of creating an email, is there a way to add a dynamic attachment (not a saved file) to the email?

I'm pretty much doing the same as this the person in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/how-to-attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp) but no-one has answered using the mailto: method. 
Im just wondering if its possible, and how to do it.

I've tried this but to no avail:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(generatedReport.DocumentBytes);
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, ct);
attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "output.pdf";                            
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:myemail &SUBJECT=Test Subject BODY=Body Text&Attachment=" + attachment);
ms.Close();
```

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately no, [the `mailto:` URL scheme does not support attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517046/does-the-mailto-in-anchor-tag-actually-support-attachments).

Comment: OK thank you, back to the drawing board for me

Answer (score 3):

In general, [the `mailto:` URL scheme does not support attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517046/does-the-mailto-in-anchor-tag-actually-support-attachments). Thus, you should not use it at all if you need it to work reliably with attachments.

Apparently, [some mail clients still support passing `Attachment=...`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21829191/87698), but they expect the `...` part to be the path of a local file. Thus, in your case, you need to

- save the file to disk (you can use a temporary file name in a temporary folder) and then
- pass the path of the file to your `mailto:` link.

Note that you will have to keep the file around until the user has actually *sent* the mail, so you might have to think about "cleaning up" those temporary files at a later time.