# Sending large number of emails in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a project in which admin wants to send updates of website via email to all registered users on web site.How to do this.? 
I am using asp.net and vb

```
    Dim em As MailMessage = New MailMessage("xxx@xxx.com", user email adress)
    em.Subject = "Updates"
    em.IsBodyHtml = True
    em.Body = txtNews.Text
    Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("localhost")
    Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@xxx.com", "xxx@com")

    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    mailClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
    mailClient.Send(em)
```

This is the backend code i am using for sending 1 email.How can i use this to send emails in bulk?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx) or [`Bcc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx) properties - these are collections of [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx).

```
mailClient.To.Add(mailAddress1)
mailClient.Bcc.Add(mailAddress1)
```

Or:

```
mailClient.To.Add(New MailAddress("my@example.com"))
mailClient.Bcc.Add(New MailAddress("my@example.com"))
```

Comment: i m new to asp.net plz tell how can i get the email ids of users from database n send them email one by one.. How to store all email ids n retrieve them one by one..?

Comment: @chetanp - Why don't you ask another question?

Comment: ok :D should i send thousands of emails together or in batch of hundreds and how to do that?

Comment: @chetanp - You don't. Ask your ISP about bulk email options. If you do it yourself you can easily end up getting your domain blacklisted as a spammer domain.

Answer (score 2):

```
  MailAddress To = new MailAddress(aryEmail[i], FromAddressTitle, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
  mailClient.Bcc.Add(To);
```

Comment: which file to import for 'To'

Comment: i think you should attach file to your message. 'To' is only MailAddress  .                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment

Comment: i m new to asp.net plz tell how can i get the email ids of users from database n send them email one by one.. How to store all email ids n retrieve them one by one..?