# How to add attachments to mailto in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
string email ="sample@gmail.com";
attachment = path + "/" + filename;
Application.OpenURL ("mailto:" + 
                      email+"
                      ?subject=EmailSubject&body=EmailBody"+"&attachment="+attachment);
```

In the above code, `attachment` isn't working. Is there any other alternative to add attachments using a mailto: link in C#?

Comment: why shouldn't you give a look to System.net.mail , you can achieve the things in a much easier way, 
It has All required class implemented like mailaddress, and attachment class for attachment purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C# MailTo with Attachment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the [MailMessage.Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments(v=vs.110).aspx) Property. Something like:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(yourAttachmentPath));
```

**OR**

You can try like this:

```
using SendFileTo;

namespace TestSendTo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MAPI mapi = new MAPI();

            mapi.AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\file1.txt");
            mapi.AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\file2.txt");
            mapi.AddRecipientTo("person1@somewhere.com");
            mapi.AddRecipientTo("person2@somewhere.com");
            mapi.SendMailPopup("testing", "body text");

            // Or if you want try and do a direct send without displaying the 
            // mail dialog mapi.SendMailDirect("testing", "body text");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses the MAPI32.dll.

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C)

> It probably won't attach the document because you are at the liberty
>   of the email client to implement the mailto protocol and include
>   parsing for the attachment clause. You may not know what mail client
>   is installed on the PC, so it may not always work - **Outlook certainly
>   doesn't support attachments using mailto**.

Comment: "Outlook certainly doesn't support attachments using mailto." 
It will work for some versions but your right, you dont know what mail clients is installed so I Suggest using C# System.Net.Mail.Attachment.

Comment: @MaxSassen:- Thats the reason after posting the answer, I added the option to use `System.Net.Mail`

Answer (score 2):

mailto: doesn't officially support attachments. I've heard Outlook 2003 will work with this syntax:

```
<a href='mailto:name@domain.com?Subject=SubjTxt&Body=Bod_Txt&Attachment=""C:\file.txt"" '>
```

Your problem has already been answered: 
[c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment#answer-1195153)

Answer (score -1):

A better way to handle this is to send the mail on the server using System.Net.Mail.Attachment.

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
{
    // Specify the file to be attached and sent.
    // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the
    // current working directory.
    string file = "data.xls";
    // Create a message and set up the recipients.
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
       "jane@contoso.com",
       "ben@contoso.com",
       "Quarterly data report.",
       "See the attached spreadsheet.");

    // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    // Add time stamp information for the file.
    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
    message.Attachments.Add(data);

    //Send the message.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try 
    {
      client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", ex.ToString());              
    }
    data.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You just copied the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment#answer-1195153 
just link to it