# open default mail client window with attachment using c#,

Tags: javascript, c#, email, outlook, email-attachments

I googling and have tried below ways to achieve this,

```
 1, mailto:
 2, Registrykeys  - @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command", "", "none");
 3, proc.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format("\"{0}\"", Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")[0].Modules[0].FileName);
```

***But this always returns outlook window only. But I want to open default mail client window which is from our device like Google chrome, MAIL Live window,OUTLOOK***

Attached Images for your reference.

[image]

Please share your answers,

Answer (score 0):

A mail client may or may not provide an API to send a mail with attachment but there is no standard way to open the default (or any) mail client with attachment.

That being said you can open the default mail client with a mailto uri :

```
    Uri myUri = new Uri("mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=TEST");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

You may try with other methods like MAPI or sending the mail yourself (SMTP) : [C# MailTo with Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment)

Comment: Thanks for your update Guillaume, 

 I am not able  to use third Party DLL and sending mail and all,

 Because our requirement is need to open mail client window along with attachment.


Please help me