# C# WPF how to send mail with attachment

Tags: c#, wpf, email, mailto

In my WPFapplication I need to be able to open the default email to send an email with attachment previously scanned.
For the scanner i used WIA and I save the scanned image in jpeg.
For email i has tried the MAILTO as follows

```
string mail1 = "abc@hotmail.com";
        string mail2 = "def@yahoo.it";
        string attach = @"C:\bla\bla\bla\file.xlsx";

        Process.Start(string.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}&CC={3}&attachment:{4}"
                                       , mail1, subject, body, mail2,attach));
```

every thing works unless ATTACHMENT when Process.start opens the default email.

you know something better than mailto? or something that gives the ability to attach files to email?

Comment: you can use `SmtpClient` in `System.Net.Mail` namespace

Comment: @dubstylee thankyou I had already used it but I do not understand how to use it with the default email without having to enter all fields. you have an advice for me on how to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# MailTo with Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload that file to a server, get a URL and include it into mailto body as a link.

Comment: Ozhan Thanks i am a beginner with c# but i will try! If you have an example to link me is greatly appreciated ;-)